# Trying to get the plaintext using php domdocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying to get the plaintext from the given html. But, it is not possible for me.
for this, what I had done is

My html is in `$content` variable

Now, I am passing $content variable to php DomDocuemnt

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTML($content)
```

Whats my next step to get the plaintext from the obtained html.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plain text ? Well just use `echo strip_tags($d);`

Comment: strip_tags is used to remove particular tags. But, I need to remove all the tags in the html.

Comment: Can you provide me the documentation link where you read that ?

Comment: http://in3.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: Strip tags will remove all tags unless you specify which ones to NOT remove.  Your link even says that.

Comment: My first thought is to iterate through the document and save all text node content.

Comment: `$d->documentElement->textContent`

Comment: When I use strip_tags on a document, the contents of a `<style>`-tag remain with the output.

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand your question but if you want the HTML code as string then 
Try this...

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($content);
$plainText = $d->textContent;
echo $plainText;
```

Comment: The "textContent" includes tags. He wants "plain" text which means the text without the tags. (i.e. an equivalent to `jQuery().text()`)

Answer (score 1):

The DOM itself does not have such functionality. You may use the [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function though. Like this:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($content);
$plainText = strip_tags($d->textContent);
echo $plainText;

// which is probably equivalent to:
$plainText = strip_tags($content);
```

*Note: using the DOMDocument() is useful to test that `$content` is correct or if you want to get a specific tag (`$main = $d->getElementByName('<main>'); $plainText = strip_tags($main[0]->textContent)`) otherwise directly using `strip_tags()` is enough.*

There are some problems as the `strip_tags()` function has no clue about the type of tag being removed. This means a sequence such as:

```
... word</p><p>more ...
```

will concatenate those two words:

```
... wordmore ...
```

This is a *difficult* problem since some tags are expected to be removed that way and others not. For example, if the user had some form of emphasis, no spaces is the right way of removing the tag:

```
che<u>val<u>   -> cheval
che<u>veaux<u> -> cheveaux
```

*(Singular and plural of "horse" in French)*

A browser has no clue either, the CSS is what tells whether a tag is a block (`<div>`) or inline (`<u>`).